# Emacs applications vs native visual tools

Tags: emacs

I have been using emacs for around 6 months in anger now, but I still find myself sometimes being alot more productive with visual tools, like various mindmapping software, JetBrains for clojure/Java development, and web browsers for web access, instead of the Emacs equivalents. Although I would like to use emacs for everything I have started to realise that maybe emacs vs the rest is really an argument to how we visualise problems, as some people are able to visualise things more easily with other tools, even die-hard emacs users. Any thoughts from die-hard emacs users on what applications they find easier to use outside of emacs?

Note:  I want to use Emacs as an operating system as in Microsoft Windows or Mac OSX, and when I talk about applications I am talking about applications installed within Emacs

Comment: Sorry, but I just don't understand....

Emacs is a tool, Vi is a tool, even Microsoft visio is a tool.
They are tools to solve problem, and if you have to worry about using only one tool, perhaps, you should try to use two...

The most important thing is to utilize different tool, weighing the cost against benefit, and use the tool effectively when it is a cost effective decision.

Comment: I guess you are right in saying that Emacs is just a tool, but I want to use it as an operating system as in Microsoft Windows or Mac OSX, and when I talk about applications I am talking about applications installed within Emacs. Anyway, thanks for your input, it has enabled me to update the question to be more clear

Comment: No question of this type can be considered complete without Emacs `org-mode`. With its presentation, table layout, HTML, TeX, and mindmap exporters, there is not much for showing other people that I don't pass through Emacs at some point ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont try and use emacs for everything. Use it for what it does best: editing. Compilation (if integrated with the right compiler).

Emacs can be used for almost anything. That does not mean it should be.

Right tool for the job is always a better way to go.

(From an emacs user since 1992... who uses other tools when it makes sense to do so).

Comment: Just out of interest, which tools do you find are better outside of emacs?

Comment: Well for example: I use Chrome as a web browser. I use a tool called SmartSVN for subversion management/checkin/checkout. I use Word for documents, Excel for spreadsheets, Visio for drawing diagrams.

Comment: Ah - perhaps I get the question a bit better. For things like code editing, I'll edit in either emacs or RAD Studio depending on the circumstances (sometimes Rad Studio is nicer - depends on the type of edit I'm doing). For my embedded C work I use emacs and activate make from within it so I can browse compilation errors and go to the relevant line. I do have an IDE for doing that same work but prefer to have all code built for deployment using makefiles, that way they are 100% controllable instead of relying on the magic parts of an IDE.